# Add 1 minute to duplicate daylight savings hour in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dst

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

[image: my data frame]

dput(sample, control = NULL):

```
list(date_time = c(1446339600, 1446343200, 1446343200, 1446346800, 
1446350400), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), test = c("0.9", "0.64", "0.7", 
"0.72", "0.88"))
```

The actual data frame has 1,217,048 rows with many repeating dates but it is sorted by date_time, and then by id similar to the sample I provided. I am trying to make the second occurrence of daylight savings different by doing something like adding 1 minute so that every other time you see '2015-11-01 02:00:00' it will change to something like '2015-11-01 02:01:00'. I need it to be different so that I can query the hour in a database without the data for the two hours being summed. What would be the best way to do something like this?

Comment: I recommend against changing the data in order to make convenient your database aggregation. If you need them to be distinct, then perhaps you should add a unique `id` for each row, instead of modifying data.

Comment: I will look into changing my table structure in my database before I resort to doing this. I hadn't thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = data.frame(date_time = c(1446339600, 1446343200, 1446343200, 1446346800, 
                       1446350400), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), test = c("0.9", "0.64", "0.7", 
                                                                    "0.72", "0.88"))
m$date_time = as.POSIXct((m$date_time + ave(m$date_time, m$date_time, FUN = seq_along) - 1) * 60, origin = "1970-01-01")
m
#            date_time id test
#1 4719-12-18 06:00:00  1  0.9
#2 4719-12-20 18:00:00  1 0.64
#3 4719-12-20 18:01:00  1  0.7
#4 4719-12-23 06:00:00  1 0.72
#5 4719-12-25 18:00:00  1 0.88
```